# dazu usage with versuchen

Tags: grammar-identification

I was reading the sentence:

> Maria versucht, Thomas dazu zu überreden, abzunehmen.

which was translated as

> Maria tries to convince Thomas to lose weight.

and I recently learnt about the dazu word - the fact that it can refer to a previous something without repeating it, irrespective of case.

But in this sentence, I was confused of the usage of "dazu"

Does the dazu refer to "versucht" or is the construct of the verb "versuchen zu" or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

In this case here **dazu** refers to the verb (infinitive with zu): **abzunehmen**.

You could also let drop dazu: Guess you can see that without **dazu** both terms in German and English are literally identical.

**dazu** would answer the question **wozu** emphasing the purpose: to lose weight.

Comment: My impression is that **dazu** belongs to **überreden** and not **abnehmen**. It's **jdn. zu etwas überreden**. **dazu** fills the place of **zu etwas**. Omitting the **versuchen** one would ask: "Wozu überredet Thomas Maria?"

Comment: I was really unsure in the moment as I sent my answer if it couldn’t be like you say. But then try to transform it: *Maria versucht Thomas zum Abnehmen zu überreden*. Then it seems to be clear.

Comment: *dazu* substitutes *zum Abnehmen*. Without the additional abstraction layer created by *versuchen*: *Maria überredet Thomas zum Abnehmen* or *Maria überredet Thomas dazu*. It's still *zu etwas überreden*.